# Pagination for custom post type on multisite not working

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I have added code to paginate posts, but it seems like it's broken or not working on not reset or simply depends on multisite installation. Take a look. Many thanks:

```
<?php
/*template to display homepage contents inside tag main*/
global $post;

switch_to_blog( 1 );
?>
<div class="intro row"><?php
echo get_field('top_text', $post->id);
$bottom=get_field('text_bottom', $post->id);
?>
</div>
<div class="row">
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
$request = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page' => 2,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post_type' => 'game'
) );
if ( $request->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $request->have_posts() ) : $request->the_post()?>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block single_game">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="wrap">
            <span class="col-lg-12"> <?php the_title();?></span>
    <div class="single-mask">
      <a  class="btn btn-orange demo" href="<?php the_permalink();?>" >Играть</a>
    </div>
<!--thumbnail image-->
    <div><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;
?>
<div class="col-xs-12">
<?php  $total_pages = $request->max_num_pages;
  if ($total_pages > 1){
    $current_page = max(1, $paged);
    echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => null,
            'next_text'    => null,
    ));
  }
}
?>
</div>
<?php

do_action('addcannonical'); ?>

</div>
<div class="row outro">
<?php
echo $bottom;
?>
</div>
<?php
```

Live example of the sites is:
 [slotsviewer.com](http://slotsviewer.com),
[http://онлайн-казино-украины.com.ua/](http://xn-----6kcbb4bhccledzdfebl4b8cxk.com.ua)

Comment: Just tested with "" but it works fine on single wordpress installation. So i simply dont uderstand why workable code i share brought bad reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Just briefly looking at the code, the first thing I spotted is `'post_type=game&posts_per_page=4&paged=$paged'`.

Because you're using single quotes, `paged` will never equal the current page.

You should use double quotes so the `$paged` variable is actually used in your query:

```
"post_type=game&posts_per_page=4&paged=$paged"
```

You can learn more about single quoted and double quoted strings in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: Thank i believe that you are dont have satisfaction to remove some errors in syntax and thanks fro the attention you paid to posts. Howerer with single quote site were paginated well and lost it functionality after migration to multisite. Through i have testes blog id option for pagination it is not working. Thanks for the support eforts anyway.

Comment: To those who are proud that they are cool with their reputation games. Debug 28 hours and say me about your reputation and cool shining ideas. Howerver no solution to pagination except real workable implementation of https://da.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ajax-pagnaition/ combined with modifying its files. Thanks to the gpl license. Any way it is not needed now but i have seen a lot of work samples with or double quotes why should i care about the rules in your type of maryland since whole of my code shows googlepage speed 91.